# Can we interpret residuals in trend-seasonality decomposition?

Tags: time-series, residuals, trend, decomposition

General case: to build a model of market for further quality estimation of our algorithms. (Predicting optimal price, demand prediction etc.)
Current approach: take two features of a product - price and demand, represent it as a time-series.
Next step I'm trying to "get rid of" time dependance for this series — by "subtraction" or "division" trend and seasonality components.
There are two main assumptions of model for decomposition: linear and multiplicative. We assume that our mean demand curve is similar to some $\exp(x)$ function, therefore we must use multiplicative approach.
I've tried some classical methods using statsmodels.tsa.seasonal: [seasonal_decompose](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.seasonal_decompose.html) and [STL](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html). With classical methods I can decompose only on one feature (demand or price).
Results are smth like this (for demand series, average on some category, data by one year):
[image]
Also used [prophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/), but with two features this time (assuming multiplicative model this time, but in prophet multiplicative model is
$$y(t) = \text{trend}(t)*(1 + \text{seasonal}(t) + \text{beta} * \text{residual}(t))$$, unlike classical
$$y(t) = \text{trend}(t)*\text{seasonal}(t)*\text{residual}(t)$$
I've fit the series, then predict it on whole data I've fitted earlier, got trend and seasonal components, got $\text{residual}(t)$:
[image: residual from Prophet]

So, two questions:

1. Is it valid way to get rid of trend and seasonal components? Especially with poor data quantity.
2. Can we interpret residual component like some "clean" demand? Or does the higher noise value not allow us to interpret this component?